Some error occurred at registration button
I am doing the registration with firebase and I got an issue the signUp button . I created a file Firebase_auth_services.dart that has this code
class FirebaseAuthServices {
  FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  Future<User?> signUpWithEmailAndPassword(
      String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential credential = await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      return credential.user;
    } catch (e) {
      print('Some error occured');
    }
    return null;
  }

  Future<User?> signInWithEmailAndPassword(
      String email, String password) async {
    try {
      UserCredential credential = await _auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(
          email: email, password: password);
      return credential.user;
    } catch (e) {
      print('Some error occured');
    }
    return null;
  }
}

and I created this method in my signup page :
class LoginScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const LoginScreen({super.key});
  @override
  _LoginPageState createState() => _LoginPageState();
}

var elements1 = [
  'Customer',
  'Business',
];
String dropdownvalue = 'Customer';
TextEditingController _usernameController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController _emailController = TextEditingController();
TextEditingController _passwordController = TextEditingController();
bool isSigningUp = false;
final FirebaseAuthServices _auth = FirebaseAuthServices();

class _LoginPageState extends State<LoginScreen> {
  @override
  void dispose() {
    _usernameController.dispose();
    _emailController.dispose();
    _passwordController.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  final _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.white,
      body: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 50.0, left: 30, right: 30),
          child: Column(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
            children: [
              Logo(),
              SignUpButton(),
              SizedBox(
                height: 30,
              ),
              Container(
                height: 62,
                width: 350,
                child: ElevatedButton(
                  style: ElevatedButton.styleFrom(
                      backgroundColor: Colors.black,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(32),
                      )),
                  onPressed: _signUp,
                  child: Text(
                    'Sign Up',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              SizedBox(
                height: 10,
              ),
              LoginButton(),
            ],
          )),
    );
  }

  void _signUp() async {
    String username = _usernameController.text;
    String email = _emailController.text;
    String password = _passwordController.text;

    User? user = await _auth.signUpWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

    if (user != null) {
      print("User is successfully created");
      Navigator.pushNamed(
          context, "/Users/lilianasanda/influfit/lib/Homepage.dart");
    } else {
      print("Some error happend");
    }
  }
}

class SignUpButton extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      children: [
        Form(
            child: Column(children: <Widget>[
          Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 10.0),
              child: FormContainerWidget(
                controller: _usernameController,
                hintText: "Username",
                isPasswordField: false,

                // prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person)),
              )),
          Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 10.0),
              child: FormContainerWidget(
                controller: _emailController,
                hintText: "Email",
                isPasswordField: false,

                // prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person)),
              )),
          Padding(
              padding:
                  const EdgeInsets.only(left: 10.0, right: 10.0, top: 10.0),
              child: FormContainerWidget(
                controller: _passwordController,
                hintText: "Password",
                isPasswordField: true,

                // prefixIcon: const Icon(Icons.person)),
              )),
          SizedBox(
            height: 20,
          ),
          Container(
              height: 62,
              width: 350,
              color: Colors.black.withOpacity(0.1),
              child: DropdownButton(
                isExpanded: true,
                value: dropdownvalue,
                icon: Icon(Icons.keyboard_arrow_down),
                items: elements1.map((String items) {
                  return DropdownMenuItem(value: items, child: Text(items));
                }).toList(),
                onChanged: (String? value) {},
              )),
  
          Row(mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start, children: <Widget>[
            Icon(
              Icons.email,
              color: Colors.white,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 40,
            ),
          ])
        ])),
      ],
    );
  }
}

and this is the error I received :

I also changed that path in _signUp method with   Navigator.pushNamed(
context, "/home") but I am receiving the same error.. Does it has something to do with the fact that I declared outside LoginPageState the controllers?  or the fact that the form field are in the SignUpButton class?

Have you defined routes? See https://docs.flutter.dev/cookbook/navigation/named-routes#2-define-the-routes.

Have you defined the routes in your app's MaterialApp widget???
if not, then the problem is clear, you need to define all your project's routes, if you are going to use Navigator.pushNamed() method,
do it like this:
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // this is your project's MaterialApp
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: LoginScreen(),
      //here you should define all the routes for your project following the same exact pattern
      routes: {
        //replace HomePage() with your own widget
        '/home': (context) => HomePage(),
        // Add more routes here ...
      },
    );
  }
}

then you can easily call
void _signUp() async {
  String username = _usernameController.text;
  String email = _emailController.text;
  String password = _passwordController.text;

  User? user = await _auth.signUpWithEmailAndPassword(email, password);

  if (user != null) {
    print("User is successfully created");
    Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/home'); // Make sure this matches the route defined in MaterialApp
  } else {
    print("Some error happened");
  }
}

let me know if it was helpful.

https://imgur.com/a/SQX96lC i have this and it still gives me error

"" I used instead of ' '
